# Forward from servlet to servlet

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic

Working on Front Controller for servlet-based application but cant find out how to forward from front contoller to regular controllers.

Here is my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FrontServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>FrontServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>IndexServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>application.controllers.IndexServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FrontServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

FrontServlet

```
public class FrontServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ServletContext context= getServletContext();
        RequestDispatcher rd = context.getRequestDispatcher("IndexServlet");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

This code returns: `java.lang.NullPointerException`. I'm using an WebLogic server.

Comment: `IndexServlet` what you mean by this in request dispatcher, it needs to be an URL, also what is `null` specifically

Comment: @JigarJoshi i need to delegate full controll (forward) to `IndexServlet`. Null in `rd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. do you have a servlet mapping for IndexServlet
2. to send to a servlet you need path like "/IndexServlet.do"

   this.getServletContext ( )
                 .getRequestDispatcher ( "/IndexServlet.do" )
                 .forward ( request , response ) ;
   or
   response.sendRedirect ( "/IndexServlet.do" );

   assuming your mapping was like

   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>IndexServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/IndexServlet.do</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   I have not tried using no extension at all instead of .do or . 
   but I would get it working with .do then experiment on changing it

Answer (score 0):

You have not given servletMapping for the IndexServlet and requestDispatcher works on URLs.

Give a proper servletMapping in the web.xml, something like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FrontServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>FrontServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>IndexServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>application.controllers.IndexServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FrontServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/frontServlet.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FrontServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/indexServlet.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And in your FrontServlet.java, give the url as "/indexServlet.html". It will work.
NullPointerException will be thrown if the view you are forwarding is not accessible. Is your IndexServlet.java forwarding request to any jsp/html? In that case, check if the jsp/html is accessible using http://{webapp}/loginjsp.jsp.